# Is it possible to force Craft to recheck available sever modules?

Tags: image-transforms, server

One of our servers hosting a Craft site has recently had ImageMagick installed on it, as we noticed that transformed animated GIFs weren't animating.

The 'Requirement Report' at `/admin/utils/serverinfo` is still reporting a 'warning' against ImageMagick (as it was before it was installed), and Craft seems to still be using GD as the freshly transformed animated GIFs still aren't animating.

Is there a way to force Craft to 'recheck' the available modules on the server (and so in my case, for it to recognise that it can now use ImageMagick)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Craft will re-run the requirement checks simply by loading that `admin/utils/serverinfo` page.  The results aren't cached.

It sounds like your box may have had the [ImageMagic](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) library installed, but not the [PHP wrapper](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) for it.  You can check by going to `admin/utils/phpinfo` and searching for `imagick` and if there are no results, it's not installed.

Alternatively maybe it is installed, but you're explicitly setting the [imageDriver](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#imageDriver) config setting to `'gd'`.  Be default, it's set to `null` which means Craft will automatically use Imagick if it sees its available.

Comment: imagick is indeed missing from `admin/utils/phpinfo`, so I assume this is the issue. Have requested installation of this also. Thanks!!